# Two levels of software in microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

today's micro-controller allows two levels of software to co-exist in single core. The levels are designated supervisor software and user software.

I am looking for an implementation of a such approach where user can have own memory space (own callable program - application level) and supervisory software (firmware) maintain hardware feature available. Is there any framework or approach to have two level software in single micro-controller?

Thank you.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: What microcontroller are you talking about?  A bootloader is sort of that.

Comment: I am talking of embedded application which can be built upon firmware - where firmware can provide controllable access to hw features. I think of 32-bit microcontroller (fixed-point) in min - PIC32, C2000, ARM-based microcntroller Cortex M3/M4 etc...

Comment: x86 processors can do that.  You're vague as to the architecture you want and also to what you're trying to actually do.

Comment: well, i am looking for an approach to take on fixed-point and not x86,

Comment: It sounds to me like you are describing embedded Linux, or another full-featured operating system such as Windows Embedded, VxWorks, or QNX.

Answer (score 0):

The Keil RTX RTOS on Cortex M3/M4 can do that.

The configuration flag for enabling it is called "Enable or disable running tasks in privileged mode" (see http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_ar_config.htm).

Unfortunately it is proprietary code.